# How can I get only some particular or selected contacts from my contact list?

Tags: android, android-contacts, import-contacts

How can I get only some particular or selected (multiple) contacts from my contact list and make a group with those selected contacts?

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent1, PICK_CONTACT_RQCODE_OLD);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here get some part of code for idea

```
URI contactData = data.getData();
Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) 
{

name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
no = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
```

here the Complete Example  [link](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2011/01/sms.html)

Comment: k thanks for u r suggestion but i want make selected contacts as a group how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the full answer. I hope this is useful anyway.

To move your contact in a group you need to update or add a new entry for its group. The group is specified in a raw in the Data table with `MIMETYPE = GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.`
So you need to:

1. Find the raw_contact_id of your raw_contact
2. Look for a raw in the data table with `RAWCONTACT_ID=yourid MIMETYPE = GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`
3. In case it exists you need to update it otherwise add it

For the way to do those things have a look to the `SampleSyncAdapter`: it gives you a lot of clues.